# How to prove $(\{2^n3^m\alpha\})_{m,n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in [0,1]?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, dynamical-systems, equidistribution

$\forall \alpha\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, how to prove $(\{2^n3^m\alpha\})_{m,n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in [0,1]? $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of x.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: do you think that $(\{2^n3^m\alpha\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(\{2^n3^m\alpha\})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ are dense in $[0,1]$ for each fixed $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @Jonas Would you please put more detail in the hint, or make it as an answer?

Comment: This is Furstenberg's theorem. For the proof, it is in Yan Bugeaud's book, 'Distribution Modulo One and Diophantine Approximation'. The proof is truly beautiful. If we replace $2$ and $3$ by any multiplicatively independent pair $r$ and $s$, the result still holds. Just reading and rewriting the proof wouldn't deserve 100 bounty, so I put it as a comment.

Comment: @i707107, could you please write the proof (or at least its idea) as an answer to this question?

Comment: This is Theorem 2.21 in the book. https://books.google.com/books?id=NeEpoAf7k0IC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=vijayaraghavan+pisot+theorem&source=bl&ots=xKIwoht2Yp&sig=Ltq9J8DrFn72ZJXtlOCkDvCBNqA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlvo61_MTNAhUDSCYKHfFzC9k4ChDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=vijayaraghavan%20pisot%20theorem&f=false Unfortunately, google book does not contain the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@zhoraster suggested me writing the proof as an answer. It is consisted of one definition, one lemma, then subsequently two pages of proof.

I will write the definition and the lemma, but I would not include full 2-page proof here.

First, we identify the fractional parts of real numbers as a one-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}$.

> **Definition** 
>   For a positive integer $n$, a set $X\subset \mathbb{T}$ is called $n$-invariant  if $nx \ \mathrm{mod} \ 1$ is in $X$ whenever $x$ belongs to $X$.
>
> **Lemma**
>   Let $\mathcal{M}=(m_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be an infinite sequence of distinct positive integers, arranged in increasing order, such that $m_{i+1}/m_i\rightarrow 1$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$. Let $X$ be a closed infinite subset of $\mathbb{T}$ that is $m_i$-invariant for every $i\geq 1$. If $0$ is a limit point of $X$, then $X=\mathbb{T}$.

The first point in the proof is that for any positive integer $u$, $\{2^{um}3^{un}\}_{m, n\in \mathbb{N}}$ can be arranged in increasing order and the sequence satisfies the hypothesis for $\{m_i\}$ of the lemma. (This is where multiplicative independence of $2$ and $3$ is used.)

The second point in the proof is setting $X$ the closure of $\{2^m3^n\alpha \ \mathrm{mod} \ 1\}$, then proving that $X$ has a rational point. (Proof by contradiction, the lemma is applied.)

Lastly, if $X$ has a rational point, then $X$ satisfies the hypothesis for $X$ of  the lemma. By the lemma, we have $X=\mathbb{T}$.

The second point is the most lengthy part of the proof. Rejecting the hypothesis '$X$ does not have any rational point' requires almost 1.5 pages of constructing a sequence of sets in $\mathbb{T}$.