# $\{\{(2^n+3^m)\alpha\}:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in [0,1]??

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, irrational-numbers, equidistribution

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational real number. I wonder whether $\{\{(2^n+3^m)\alpha\}:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$  is dense in [0,1] in which  $\{x\}$ means the fractional part of x.

This is equivalent to the following:
$$\forall \alpha\in(0,1)\setminus\mathbb{Q},E_j=\mathrm{closure~of ~}\left\{\{j^n\alpha\}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\},j=2,3,\mathrm{~then~}E_2+E_3=[0,1].$$

In the proof of the case [$2^n3^m\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836761/how-to-prove-2n3m-alpha-m-n-in-mathbbn-is-dense-in-0-1), the semi-group property of $\{2^n3^m:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is used. But this property is missing in the above question.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $\{\{(2^n+3^m)\alpha\}:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM.Yes, you are right. my problem concerns fractional part.

Comment: @DavidLee It seems that this question is hard. Would you be able to provide some background for coming up with this problem? or is this used somewhere else? or just for curiosity?

Comment: This one requires knowledge of expansion of $\alpha$ in two different bases $2$ and $3$. For some known results, see [this](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/BasesdiffDEF1.pdf). I hope someone comes up with a solution.

Comment: @i707107. Recently,I am working on Furstenberg's theorem which says that $ \{\{2^n3^m\alpha\}:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in [0,1) whenever $\alpha$ is irrational. After proving Furstenberg's theorem, I come up the problem as I stated above. Recently, I find if the above problem is right(dense holds), then Furstenberg conjecture will be valid.

Comment: Furstenberg conjectured that $\{\{2^n3^m\alpha\}:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly distributed in [0,1).